# readthedocs build fails to produce sphinx documentation with shields.io svg badges

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

My latest Sphinx documentaion fails when trying to build it with readthedocs. It has apperently something to do with the fact that I am trying to incorporate some badges from https://shields.io/. These badges are .svg graphic files.

I probably need to do some tweaking in my `conf.py` file?

On my local machine, I am able to produce the Sphinx documentation and all HTML files do look OK.

Here's an excerpt of my `conf.py` file:

```
# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = [
    "nbsphinx",
    "numpydoc",
    "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
    "sphinx_copybutton",
    "sphinx.ext.napoleon",
]

napoleon_google_docstring = False
napoleon_numpy_docstring = True
numpy_validation_checks = {all}

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ["_templates"]

# List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
# directories to ignore when looking for source files.
# This pattern also affects html_static_path and html_extra_path.
exclude_patterns = []


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#
html_theme = "sphinx_rtd_theme"

# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = []
```

Here's the text output: https://readthedocs.org/api/v2/build/17082650.txt

[image]

Comment: What error are you referring to? Is it "LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .svg."?

Comment: @mzjn To be honest, I am not even sure what causes the build to fail. I saw this "LaTeX Error", but is it the cause of failure? If yes, what to do about it?

Comment: Some further research revealed that readthedocs.org is not able to render .svg bades without configuring a converter. I therefore enriched the question with an excerpt of my ``conf.py``.

Comment: HTML seems to be fine as you say. The errors appear when generating PDF output from LaTeX. Do you care about the PDF output? The conf.py excerpt contains nothing about LaTeX/PDF configuration.

Comment: I don't necessarily need PDF. I already disabled PDF and ePub in the readthedocs administrator settings, with no success. Same error. There ist nothing with respect to PDF/ePub in ``conf.py``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you may have disabled the epub and PDF builds in the RTD UI, you must take note in the RTD UI under Advanced Settings > Default settings:

> These settings can be configured using a [configuration file](https://docs.readthedocs.io/page/config-file/v2.html). That's the recommended way to set up your project. Settings listed here are ignored when using a configuration file.

Therefore you must be using a configuration file that enables both pdf and epub builds. Lo and behold:

https://github.com/andreas-vester/df2img/blame/3ba6e046c8d30ab3896b23835513740bd5aa97fa/.readthedocs.yaml#L12-L14

```
formats:
  - pdf
  - epub
```